# C++ memory endiannes under question for me

Tags: c++, memory, endianness

For example, I have an array of 512 bytes called ***blocks_data***, I create an ***unsigned long long*** pointer, which points to the ***512 - 8 = 508*** byte in the array. I dereference the pointer and assign a value, let it be ***3***. As I know, Intel x86_64 uses little-endian byte order. But when I print every byte in the array I see this:

```
0 ...(54 zero bytes between)... 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                                  ulonglong in mem
```

Instead of expected:

```
0 ...(54 zero bytes between)... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
```

Because little-endian byte order must mean that the least significant byte is positioned at the end. What have I done wrong and may not know?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness answers your question very clearly.

Comment: Littleendian means that you start with the Little End (of egg). Term is sourced from Gulliver book, easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

*Endiannes* article on Wikipedia explained me everything. Thanks, @Sam Varshavchik, I just was inattentive

> A big-endian system stores the most significant byte of a word at the smallest memory address and the least significant byte at the largest. A little-endian system, in contrast, stores the least-significant byte at the smallest address.